# DRF making DateTimeField naive without considering default timezone

Tags: python, django, datetime, serialization, django-rest-framework

The default timezone is `TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'` and `USE_TZ = False`

In the request data, I have `time` field whose value is something like this:

```
'2017-04-05T14:42:52.472+05:00'
```

And when I do this:

```
serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data)
if serializer.is_valid():
    ...
```

that time field is converted to this inside `validated_data`:

```
2017-04-05 09:42:52.472000
```

That is, it is making the time naive. However, it is not considering my default timezone. I would expect it to convert the time to Chicago time first and then make it naive to this:

```
2017-04-05 04:42:52.875000
```

just like how `django.utils.timezone.make_naive()` works.

I am solving this by using that `make_naive`. However, I don't think this is a good solution.

Serializer:

```
class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    time = UnixTimestampField()

    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = (
            'latitude',
            'longitude',
            'time'
        )

    def validate(self, attrs):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        if user.is_authenticated():
            attrs['tracking_id'] = user.tracking.id
            attrs['device_id'] = user.current_device.id
        return attrs
```

UnixTimestampField:

```
class UnixTimestampField(serializers.DateTimeField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        if not value:
            return value

        return int(value.timestamp())
```

Is this the default behavior of DRF? What is the proper way of solving this?

Comment: Can you write your serializer class here?

Comment: @MohammadMustaqeem posted it

Comment: What is `UnixTimestampField`? From where it is imported?

Comment: @MohammadMustaqeem posted it as well. It just inherits from `DateTimeField` and overrides `to_representation`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think you have a mis-understanding of the meaning of your timestamp.

```
2017-04-05T14:42:52.472+05:00
```

This timestamp indicates 5 hours ahead of zulu.  So the converted timestamp of:

```
2017-04-05 09:42:52.472000
```

Has been converted to UTC, and this timestamp looks like I would expect in UTC.
And while the timestamp is naive, it is also UTC, so I do not think that is in
and of itself a problem.

> However, it is not considering my default timezone. I would expect it to
>   convert the time to Chicago time first and then make it naive to this:

I believe this is also a misunderstanding.  The original timestamp, via the 
`+05:00` was indicating what timezone it was relative to.  Your local timezone should not have anything to do with it.

In general the correct way to deal with timestamps is to convert them to UTC as soon as possible.  Then keep them as UTC as long as possible, and only convert them back into a timezone representation when displaying to the user.  If they must be stored with a time offset, the format you started with is a good way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!